# How to Set Form Bean before it goes to JSP page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I am an absolute beginner. So please bear with me if I miss the obvious.

Environment I am using: Spring Portlet MVC (3.0), Liferay 6.0.6

I have a controller, a form bean and a JSP page. 
I am able to successfully submit a form and get the form bean by using the below code. However I am stuck on how to preload some values into my form bean before the bean is forwarded to JSP. Can somebody point out the right direction:

My Controller:

```
@ActionMapping(params = "spring_action=resetPasswordViewAction")
protected void resetPasswordAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, Map<String, Object> model, ActionResponse actionResponse, @RequestParam String customerId, @RequestParam String userName) {
    model.put("customerId", customerId);//Preload form bean value with this
    model.put("userName", userName);//Preload form bean value with this
    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("spring_render", "resetPasswordView");
}

@RenderMapping(params = "spring_render=resetPasswordView")
protected ModelAndView resetPasswordView(RenderRequest renderRequest, Map<String, Object> model) {
    return new ModelAndView("resetPassword", model);
}

@ActionMapping(params = "spring_action=resetPasswordUpdateAction")
protected void resetPasswordUpdateAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, Map<String, Object> model, ActionResponse actionResponse, final ResetPassword resetPasswordCriteria) {
    LOG.info(resetPasswordCriteria.toString());// Form values are retrieved successfully
    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("spring_render", "resetPasswordView");
}

@ModelAttribute("resetPasswordCriteria")
public ResetPassword getResetPasswordCriteria() {
    return new ResetPassword();
}
```

My JSP Page:

```
<form:form id="resetPasswordForm" name="resetPasswordForm" commandName="resetPasswordCriteria" method="post" action="${resetPasswordUpdateActionURL}">

    <form:label path="customerId" /><!--Preload this field value-->
    <form:label path="userName" /><!--Preload this field value-->
    <form:password path="password" />
    <form:password path="confirmPassword" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form:form>
```

Form Bean:

```
public class ResetPassword {
    private String customerId = "";
    private String userName = "";
    private String password = "";
    private String confirmPassword = "";
    //Getters Setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your rendering method *resetPasswordView*, place an object named **resetPasswordCriteria** (your commandName in jsp) of type **ResetPassword** to the model.

Comment: Yup, I changed the signature of both the action and the render to match it like...  @RenderMapping(params = "spring_render=resetPasswordViewRender")
 protected ModelAndView resetPasswordViewRender(@ModelAttribute("resetPasswordCriteria") final ResetPassword resetPasswordCriteria,RenderRequest renderRequest, Map<String, Object> model)